# Properties of CV (Coefficient of Variation) for the sum of normal random variables

Tags: variance, normality-assumption, coefficient-of-variation

Given two normally distributed random variable $X_1$ and $X_2$ given the mean and the variance to be $(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$ and $(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$ respectively, we know that the mean and standard deviation for a random variable $Y = X_1 + X_2$ is given by $\mu_1 + \mu_2$ and $\sqrt{\sigma_1^{2} + \sigma_2^{2}}$.

I am wondering what can be commented algebraically on the properties of CV ~ "coefficient of variance" for the random variables $X_1, X_2$ and $Y$. To be specific, we know the following,

$$ \text{CV}_Y = \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_1^{2} + \sigma_2^{2}}}{\mu_1 + \mu_2}, \text{CV}_{X_{1}} = \frac{\sigma_1}{\mu_1}, \text{CV}_{X_{2}} = \frac{\sigma_2}{\mu_2}  $$

Since $ \text{CV}_Y$ can not be represented directly by a function of $\text{CV}_{X_{1}}$ and $\text{CV}_{X_{2}}$, I am wondering if there is a property for the nature of the quantity 
$$ \frac{\text{CV}_Y}{\text{CV}_{X_{1}} + \text{CV}_{X_{2}}} $$.

Would it be always less than 1, or does it have a specific range? I must mention the data I am working with is positive, so to empirically test what happens I did this following experiment,

```
cv = np.zeros(1000)
means = np.zeros(1000)
stds = np.zeros(1000)
mu = np.random.normal(size=1000)
sigma = np.random.normal(size=1000)
for sample in range(1000):
    m = np.random.normal(mu[sample], np.abs(sigma[sample]), 1000)
    m += np.abs(np.min(m))
    means[sample] = np.mean(m)
    stds[sample] = np.std(m)
    cv[sample] = stds[sample] / means[sample]
```

Note the addition with the absolute minimum is to stop the negative data. Additionally, I computed the quantities of interest as following,

```
samples = np.arange(1000)
combo = {}
combo_gain = {}
gain_vs_sum = []
for i,j in itertools.combinations(samples,2):
    combo[(i,j)] = np.sqrt(stds[i]**2 + stds[j]**2) / (means[i] + means[j])
    combo_gain[(i,j)] = combo[(i,j)] / (cv[i] + cv[j])
    gain_vs_sum += [[combo_gain[(i,j)], means[i] + means[j]]]
```

I plotted the quantity $ \frac{\text{CV}_Y}{\text{CV}_{X_{1}} + \text{CV}_{X_{2}}} $ with respect to $\mu_1 + \mu_2$ (captured in `gain_vs_sum`), and got the following plot,
[image: Plot[![]]][1](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)

It would be great to find more references and rigorous treatment about the above quantity.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!, please note that in this case, I assume all the observed data to be positive. Thereby, that case does not arise.